# How can I show that this complex inequality holds inside a given disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Within the context of a larger proof, I'm trying to show, with 
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = e^{z} - 1, \hspace{1.5mm} g(z) = \frac{-1}{z}
\end{equation*}
and $z$ complex, that $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ in $B_{r}(2in)$, with $n$ a non-zero integer, i.e. an arbitrarily small open ball centred around a multiple of 2 on the imaginary axis. In trying to do this I'm just unsure of how to use the exponentional really, so any help or advice would be appreciated. Also if this is not true then that would be good to know too, as I must have made a mistake prior to this in the proof.

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Maybe try doing some Taylor estimates with sine and cosine for the values they take on $2n$. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Since this is false close to $0$ you must specify the radius $r$ of the disc.

Comment: You write $B_r(2n)$, but you also write "on the imaginary axis". These do not fit together. Since there is no problem with showing the inequality on the real axis, I suppose you mean $B_r(2in)$. Can you confirm?

Comment: @AD It would seem you are right, as the answer below demonstrates. Thank you all.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you are right, I actually wrote that originally and then edited it thinking I had made a mistake, but you are correct. It's been a long day.

Comment: Note that then the inequality can't hold for all $n$. $\lvert e^{2in} - 1\rvert = 2\lvert \sin n\rvert$, and when $n$ is close to a multiple of $\pi$, that is smaller than $\frac{1}{2\lvert n\rvert}$. I don't _know_ whether that happens for infinitely many $n$, but it is very likely. And it certainly happens for some $n$, for example $n = 355$.